# HTML input elements overlap absolute navbar

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. I am using the following webiste code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "segoe ui", roboto, oxygen, ubuntu, cantarell, "fira sans", "droid sans", "helvetica neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) ), url(src/assets/images/background2.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color:#464646;
}




.login, .register {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.login h1, .register h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #5b6574;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee0e4;
}

.login .links, .register .links {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.login .links a, .register .links a {
  color: #adb2ba;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.login .links a:hover, .register .links a:hover {
  color: #9da3ac;
}

.login .links a.active, .register .links a.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #547430;
  color: #547430;
}

.login form, .register form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.login form label, .register form label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 12%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #547430;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.login form input[type="password"], .login form input[type="text"], .login form input[type="email"], .register form input[type="password"], .register form input[type="text"], .register form input[type="email"] {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #dee0e4;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.login form input[type="submit"], .register form input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #547430;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.login form input[type="submit"]:hover, .register form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #2868c7;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.login form #rememberme, .register form #rememberme {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #000;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.login form #rememberme input, .register form #rememberme input {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.login form .msg, .register form .msg {
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.login form > a, .register form > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5b6574;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.login form > a:hover, .register form > a:hover {
  color: #394049;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .login, .register {
    width: 95%;
  }
}






a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #547430;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: #fff;
}

/* LOGO */
.logo {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Rockwell;
}

/* NAVBAR MENU */
.menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #7ead47;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 5px 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* DROPDOWN MENU */
.services {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  background-color: rgb(1, 139, 139);
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: absolute; /*WITH RESPECT TO PARENT*/
  display: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  top: 35px;
}

.dropdown li + li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.dropdown li {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  width: 8em;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown li:hover {
  background-color: #4c9e9e;
}

.services:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}




/*RESPONSIVE NAVBAR MENU STARTS*/
/* CHECKBOX HACK */
/*HAMBURGER MENU*/
.hamburger {
  display: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  user-select: none;
}
/* APPLYING MEDIA QUERIES */
@media (max-width: 900px) {

  .menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #547430;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 16px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    left: -100%;
  }

  .menu li:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #7ead47;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
  }

  .menu li + li {
    margin-top: 12px;
  }

  input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .menu{
    left: 0%;
  }

  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }

  .dropdown {
    left: 50%;
    top: 30px;
    transform: translateX(35%);
  }

  .dropdown li:hover {
    background-color: #4c9e9e;
  }

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>EWA</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">Audio Diary</div>
    <ul class="nav-links">

      <!-- USING CHECKBOX HACK -->
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_toggle" />
      <label for="checkbox_toggle" class="hamburger">&#9776;</label>

      <!-- NAVIGATION MENUS -->
      <div class="menu">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Explore</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <div class="login">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="/login" class="active">Login</a>
      <a href="/register">Register</a>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <label for="email">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" required>
      <label for="password">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
      </label>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required>
      <label id="rememberme">
        <input type="checkbox" name="rememberCode">Remember me
      </label>
      <a href="/forgotpassword">Forgot Password?</a>
      <div class="msg"></div>
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

But as you can see the checkbox from "Remember me" goes over the navbar, now I have already read that I can add `z-index: 9999;` to the navbar, or set the position to `relative` instead of `absolute`, but that places my navbar menu next to the logo on mobile. How can I let my navbar overlap all content on mobile, while maintaining the looks it has now?

PS: To see the wrong result, switch to full screen and shrink your window in width!

Here is an image of the wrong result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues.

Your toggle checkbox shows. You could apply some standard techniques to the checkbox to move it off screen. Note that I've also added `aria-hidden="true"` to prevent screen readers from announcing it.

```
.offscreen {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}
```

Your form checkbox shows over the menu because of the transform. If you disable the scaling rule you see it disappear. You can add a low `z-index` value to the menu to resolve this.

```
.menu {
  ...
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "segoe ui", roboto, oxygen, ubuntu, cantarell, "fira sans", "droid sans", "helvetica neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url(src/assets/images/background2.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #464646;
}

.offscreen {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}

.login,
.register {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.login h1,
.register h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #5b6574;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee0e4;
}

.login .links,
.register .links {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.login .links a,
.register .links a {
  color: #adb2ba;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.login .links a:hover,
.register .links a:hover {
  color: #9da3ac;
}

.login .links a.active,
.register .links a.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #547430;
  color: #547430;
}

.login form,
.register form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.login form label,
.register form label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 12%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #547430;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.login form input[type="password"],
.login form input[type="text"],
.login form input[type="email"],
.register form input[type="password"],
.register form input[type="text"],
.register form input[type="email"] {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #dee0e4;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.login form input[type="submit"],
.register form input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #547430;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.login form input[type="submit"]:hover,
.register form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #2868c7;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.login form #rememberme,
.register form #rememberme {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #000;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.login form #rememberme input,
.register form #rememberme input {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.login form .msg,
.register form .msg {
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.login form>a,
.register form>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5b6574;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.login form>a:hover,
.register form>a:hover {
  color: #394049;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .login,
  .register {
    width: 95%;
  }
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #547430;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: #fff;
}


/* LOGO */

.logo {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Rockwell;
}


/* NAVBAR MENU */

.menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  font-size: 18px;
  z-index: 9;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #7ead47;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 5px 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* DROPDOWN MENU */

.services {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  background-color: rgb(1, 139, 139);
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: absolute;
  /*WITH RESPECT TO PARENT*/
  display: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  top: 35px;
}

.dropdown li+li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.dropdown li {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  width: 8em;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown li:hover {
  background-color: #4c9e9e;
}

.services:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}


/*RESPONSIVE NAVBAR MENU STARTS*/


/* CHECKBOX HACK */


/*HAMBURGER MENU*/

.hamburger {
  display: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  user-select: none;
}


/* APPLYING MEDIA QUERIES */

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #547430;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 16px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    left: -100%;
  }
  .menu li:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #7ead47;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
  }
  .menu li+li {
    margin-top: 12px;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:checked~.menu {
    left: 0%;
  }
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
  .dropdown {
    left: 50%;
    top: 30px;
    transform: translateX(35%);
  }
  .dropdown li:hover {
    background-color: #4c9e9e;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>EWA</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">Audio Diary</div>
    <ul class="nav-links">

      <!-- USING CHECKBOX HACK -->
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_toggle" class="offscreen" aria-hidden="true" />
      <label for="checkbox_toggle" class="hamburger">&#9776;</label>

      <!-- NAVIGATION MENUS -->
      <div class="menu">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Explore</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="login">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="/login" class="active">Login</a>
      <a href="/register">Register</a>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <label for="email">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" required>
      <label for="password">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
      </label>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required>
      <label id="rememberme">
        <input type="checkbox" name="rememberCode">Remember me
      </label>
      <a href="/forgotpassword">Forgot Password?</a>
      <div class="msg"></div>
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with z-index. Your checkbox is above the menu area. Add `z-index: 1` to `.menu` and it will be hidden.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "segoe ui", roboto, oxygen, ubuntu, cantarell, "fira sans", "droid sans", "helvetica neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) ), url(src/assets/images/background2.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color:#464646;
}




.login, .register {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.login h1, .register h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #5b6574;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee0e4;
}

.login .links, .register .links {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.login .links a, .register .links a {
  color: #adb2ba;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.login .links a:hover, .register .links a:hover {
  color: #9da3ac;
}

.login .links a.active, .register .links a.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #547430;
  color: #547430;
}

.login form, .register form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.login form label, .register form label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 12%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #547430;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.login form input[type="password"], .login form input[type="text"], .login form input[type="email"], .register form input[type="password"], .register form input[type="text"], .register form input[type="email"] {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #dee0e4;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.login form input[type="submit"], .register form input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #547430;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.login form input[type="submit"]:hover, .register form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #2868c7;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.login form #rememberme, .register form #rememberme {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #000;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.login form #rememberme input, .register form #rememberme input {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.login form .msg, .register form .msg {
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.login form > a, .register form > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5b6574;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.login form > a:hover, .register form > a:hover {
  color: #394049;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .login, .register {
    width: 95%;
  }
}






a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #547430;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: #fff;
}

/* LOGO */
.logo {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Rockwell;
}

/* NAVBAR MENU */
.menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #7ead47;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 5px 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* DROPDOWN MENU */
.services {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  background-color: rgb(1, 139, 139);
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: absolute; /*WITH RESPECT TO PARENT*/
  display: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  top: 35px;
}

.dropdown li + li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.dropdown li {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  width: 8em;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown li:hover {
  background-color: #4c9e9e;
}

.services:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}




/*RESPONSIVE NAVBAR MENU STARTS*/
/* CHECKBOX HACK */
/*HAMBURGER MENU*/
.hamburger {
  display: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  user-select: none;
}
/* APPLYING MEDIA QUERIES */
@media (max-width: 900px) {

  .menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #547430;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 16px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    left: -100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .menu li:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #7ead47;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
  }

  .menu li + li {
    margin-top: 12px;
  }

  input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .menu{
    left: 0%;
  }

  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }

  .dropdown {
    left: 50%;
    top: 30px;
    transform: translateX(35%);
  }

  .dropdown li:hover {
    background-color: #4c9e9e;
  }

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>EWA</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">Audio Diary</div>
    <ul class="nav-links">

      <!-- USING CHECKBOX HACK -->
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_toggle" />
      <label for="checkbox_toggle" class="hamburger">&#9776;</label>

      <!-- NAVIGATION MENUS -->
      <div class="menu">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Explore</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <div class="login">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="/login" class="active">Login</a>
      <a href="/register">Register</a>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <label for="email">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" required>
      <label for="password">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
      </label>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required>
      <label id="rememberme">
        <input type="checkbox" name="rememberCode">Remember me
      </label>
      <a href="/forgotpassword">Forgot Password?</a>
      <div class="msg"></div>
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```